# AspectJ pointcut expression for all classes that contains a especific word in their names

Tags: expression, aspectj, contains, classname, pointcut

What's up? folks!

I'm trying to intercept all classes that contains a specific word in their names... something as below:

```java
@Before("execution(* com.domain.model.*.*Repository.save(..))")
```

I have the following methods to intercept:

```java
com.domain.model.user.UserRepository.save(User user);
com.domain.model.xpto.XPTORepository.save(XPTO xpto);
com.domain.model.foo.FooRepository.save(Foo foo);
```

I have tried this: (worked, but looks horrible)

```java
@Before("execution(* *.save(..)) && within(com.domain.model..*)")
public void validateBeforeSave(final JoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    if (jp.getSignature().toString().contains("Repository.")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with your own suggestion?

```java
execution(* com.domain.model.*.*Repository.save(..))
```

should work nicely with the sample package + class names you provided. If is does not work your real package names are different, e.g. you have more than one subpackage below `model`. In this case you can make the pointcut more generic using the `..` construct which is also used in your ugly workaround:

```java
execution(* com.domain.model..*Repository.save(..))
```

Or maybe your `*Repository` classes all inherit from a common superclass or implement the same interface, e.g. `interface com.domain.model.Repository` or `abstract class com.domain.model.BaseRepository`. In this case you could do without the string matching and just use something like

```java
execution(* com.domain.model.Repository+.save(..))
```

or

```java
execution(* com.domain.model.BaseRepository+.save(..))
```

The `+` means "this class and all of its subclasses".